# Software Development Team HUD

Tags: project-management

I read an article a while back about a development company that had a dedicated Monitor to display a web app that charted completed task by team member, kind of like a sales chart for software development. I'm thinking of implementing something like this but I can't for the life of me find that article or that tool. I think it was a ruby on rails tool, but I can't be sure.

Does this ring a bell with anybody? can you point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Funny: As I am reading your question, the banner ad to the right shows a screenshot of Telerik TeamPulse's dashboard, which looks exactly like what you describe.

Comment: I see the ad. "Unfortunately", I'm not in a windows environment.;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it!
http://lifehacker.com/5489288/staying-motivated-at-work-with-a-status-board